# Is my date in the correct format to Query a DateRange using MongoDB and Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've tried to find a solution looking at similar problems. One main issue that I've come across is that the Date is in a String format or not in the some altered form. I have a large file of data in JSON format. First I read through that file and convert each String to a date OBJ , the push all my data to my MongoDB.

convert to date.

```
var fs = require('fs');




fs.readFile('data.txt',function(err,data){
   var x = [];

   if(err) throw err;

   var buf = new Buffer(data);
   x = buf.toString();
   x = JSON.parse(x);

   //console.log(x);
   for(var a in x){
    x[a].TrxDate=new Date(x[a].TrxDate);
   }
   x = JSON.stringify(x);
   fs.writeFile('data.txt',x,callback()); 
});


function callback(){
    console.log('finished');
}
```

my date field in the DB

```
"TxDate": "2015-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"
```

Here is my query. It returns nothing found

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');

var url = 'blank';


MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
    if(err){
        console.log('unable to connect to the mongodb server Error:',err);

    }else {
        console.log('connection good:',url);

        var collection = db.collection('records');

        collection.find({TxDate: { $gte: new Date('2015-07-01')}}).toArray(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else if (result.length){
                console.log('Found',result);    
            }else{
                console.log('Nothing found');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? Something I just thought of, Is it possible for me to check the type of the object int the DB?

Comment: just needed to send in a string instead of a date object. '2015-07-01' instead of new Date('2015-07-01') , if anyone can find any other errors thanks. I've solved my immediate problem

Comment: That will work, but for better flexibility and efficiency, you should consider storing your dates as native BSON Dates instead of strings.